# Continous deployment in wso2 api manager

Tags: api, deployment, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

Do i have the options of continuous deployment in wso2 api manager. For example - I have configured an API in test region & once API testing is done i need to promote the API to UAT region automatically rather than login again in UAT region configure the same API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we don't have that support. We have this feature in our roadmap.

Comment: Is there any answer please on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by programmatically. write a java client to get the api details from one environment and then publish to the target environment using apimanager's publisher apis[1].

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publisher+APIs

Comment: This looks good. is there any other process improvised on this? If yes, can you please let us know